# Can't install rbenv past 2.4.0?

Tags: homebrew, rbenv

So I have rbenv install on OSX with Homebrew, and I can't seem to install past 2.4.0. Im trying to install 2.4.1 but it complains it's not in `rbenv install --list`.

I've tried `brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build` which it suggests. I've uninstalled ruby/rbenv/ruby-build and reinstalled them. i've ran `brew doctor` and all this:

I do get this when running the `curl` command suggested on the rbenv github.

```
$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: multiple
  You seem to have multiple `rbenv-install' in the following locations.
  Please pick just one installation and remove the others.

  /usr/local/var/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/rbenv-install
  /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install

Counting installed Ruby versions: 7 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: warning
  rbenv-gem-rehash functionality is now included in rbenv core. Please remove the plugin.
    (found in `/usr/local/var/rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash/etc/rbenv.d/exec/~gem-rehash.bash')
```

I’m not super proficient in understanding what this means? I think in the past I installed rbenv without brew possibly. So im not entirely sure if this is the problem. But I know I should be able to install rbenv past 2.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have already installed rbenv with bash. When you use this version - you should update ruby-build by updating its git repo at `.rbenv`.

First of all try to uninstall all kinds of rbenv from your machine:

2. `brew uninstall rbenv`
3. grep your FS to find any artifacts from bash-installed rbenv, and remove them

After that try clean installation with brew.

Comment: I had actually done that previously. I'd prefer to stick with brew, so is there a way to be able to uninstall NON-brew rbenv?

Comment: yeah, run `find / -name "rbenv"` to find all rbenv occurences.
Proceeding with brew is right solution.

Comment: Im not exactly that proficient using grep. Is there a way to use it to only find installs? When I tried it, it was returning anything with the grep text inside of it.

Comment: Actually, rbenv has a simple uninstall instruction https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv check it